# How to find out the update function of the update button in a certain folder in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone here know the name of the directory where this update button's mysql update code is located?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GuUU.jpg)

Comment: what you will do with that button?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly i guess you have many places to search inside wordpress.

While the real mysql update could be in wp-includes/post.php inside the wp_insert_post() function the real mysql is calculated runtime with all the args coming from all the plugins/theme that may add information to the post

You can start searching the post_update hook (documented here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/)